# ES6 - Attach class prototype to singleton

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, es6-class

I'm wondering what the best way is to attach a 'new' class to an existing instance.

For example: I have a 'worker' class, that needs to 'extend' to an existing IPC class instance, so it can communicate over the ipc channel.

```
class Worker {
    constructor(ipc) {
        this.__proto__ = ipc;
        this.__proto__.constructor = Worker;
    }
}
```

And then I can use it like this:

```
const worker = new Worker(myCurrentIpc);
worker.send('blabla') /* Calls super instance ipc method */
```

This is bad practices as it kills performance.. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/nl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/setPrototypeOf

And in this case, the 'send' method will be called millions of times.

So in a use case like this, what would you recommend?

I can also create every function again in the Worker instance, and then call ipc.func() in that method, but that also feels like an anti-pattern.

Thanks

***Clarification:***

I have one 'host' worker (main).. That has an already initialised IPC (node-ipc) instance..

When ever I create a worker 'child', I want to use the (already existing) parent IPC instance to connect to the child worker..

So it would be really nice, that when ever I create a new Worker({ipc:ipc}), I can attach the worker.prototype to the IPC instance.. Thus I can just do worker.send() and the IPC instance knows Its going from the main->child channel..

Comment: Is `ipc` another class by itself, or just a plain object or class instance?

Comment: ipc is an already initialized class instance

Comment: Your parentworker-childworker relationship does not sound like a subclass relation. You should favour composition over inheritance here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it was already mentioned, it is the case for [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) principle. Worker object is supposed to keep `ipc` instance as private property and wrap its methods if it is supposed to expose some of them:

```
class Worker {
  constructor(ipc) {
    this.ipc = ipc;
  }

  send(...args) {
    return this.ipc.send(...args);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you *really* want to access the `ipc` methods with `worker.theIpcMethod`, you could use a "class factory", a function that creates a class extending a specific value:

```
function WorkerClassFactory(ipc) {
    return class Worker extends ipc {
        //contents of Worker class here
    }
}
```

Then you create a concrete `Worker` class or a given IPC:

```
let Worker = WorkerClassFactory(myIpcInstance);

//then somewhere
let worker_instance = new Worker();
worker_instance.doStuff();
```

Of course, you could create it once and instantiate it throughout the program, so you get consistent `instanceof` behaviour.

---

**BUT!** This is a really weird thing to do, I would really recommend simply exposing a read-only property and use it from there, or even just wrapping the IPC interface into something simpler to use (if your class simply exposes methods of IPC, why not use IPC directly?).

```
class Worker {
    constructor(ipc) {
        this._ipc = ipc;
    }

    get ipc() {
        return this._ipc;
    }
}

new Worker(ipc).ipc.send("asdasdasd");
```

Comment: Thanks for the code examples @Kroltan... I'm in a way relieved that both you and synthet1c are pushing into the direction of just making ipc a variable inside the class.. Started to feel like a was pushing the inheritance thingy to far

Comment: @DutchKev Yeah, doing this is sort of an abuse on prototypical inheritance. It's also inconsistent, because if you call `WorkerClassFactory` twice with the same value of `ipc`, instances of that class will not necessarily be `instanceof` that worker. Of course, the Factory could cache its outputs, but that's completely overengineering a questionable workaround.

Comment: @DutchKev This is what [composition over inheritance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance) principle is about. It isn't a rule of thumb but is totally applicable here.

Comment: @estus, good read thanks! I was looking for some black on white documentation about the 'best practice' principle, and mostly as you point out, where 'the line' is between inheritance and composition that one should keep in mind..

Answer (score 1):

My bad, I didn't understand the question.

This may be a little more what you are looking for.

Here we are decoupling the `IPC` object and passing it into the `Worker` constructor, then from the instance you are simply delegating to the IPC singleton.

As the comments say using class in not needed.

```js
// here is a singleton with a single static method. using class in not really
// neccasary here, you could just use an object with a single propery
class IPC {
  static send(val) {
    console.log('IPC::send', val)
  }
}

class Worker {
  // constructor takes the ipc as a variable and saves it to itself
  constructor(ipc) {
    this.ipc = ipc
  }
  // the send method simply calls the ipc send function
  send(val) {
    this.ipc.send(val)
  }
}

// create a new worker
const worker = new Worker(IPC);

worker.send('blabla')
```

Comment: Thanks for the code example @synthet1c, but then IPC is not a singleton, but a new class.. I want to attach a 'new' instance to a singeton/existing instance

Comment: You shouldn't use a `class` for singletons. If you make it a class, create instances with `new`, if you want a singleton then use an object literal.